# How to write the sql for select only some letters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have the data like this

```
112219/18
112219/1
```

But I only want

```
18
1
```

How can i write the sql code? I use sql server

Comment: `SELECT '18 1'` :) Seriously though, you need to explain the pattern/rules for extracting those specific numbers.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: I want only the number after /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(colName, CHARINDEX('/', colName) + 1, LEN(colName)) FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the above solutions, or use a scalar function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunctionName
(
@param nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @char char = N'/'
    IF @Param IS NULL OR NOT @param LIKE '%'+@char+'%' RETURN @param;
    SET @param = SUBSTRING(@param, CHARINDEX(@char, @param)+1, LEN(@param))
    RETURN @param;
END
```

After that you can use it:

```
SELECT dbo.YourFunctionName(YourDataColumn) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql-server you could try using right() and charindex()

```
    select  RIGHT(my_col, LEN(my_col) - CHARINDEX ('/', my_col))
    from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract from this query

```
select right(yourColumnName, charindex('/', reverse(yourColumnName)) - 1) from yourTable
```

Comment: I try to use this query : Select right (A.B,charindex('/',reverse(A.B)),-1) from A          but it didn't work. could you tell me if I did something wrong?